# Get path params in react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a router link through my application,

In this scenario, I have three files.

`App.js`

`Book.js`

`DetailedView.js`

I have inside of Book built up a `<Link>` that only appears when hovered ( over a book cover )

```
{this.state.isHovered ? (
   <Link to={`/details/${this.props.book.industryIdentifiers[1].identifier}`}>
<div className="hover-box"></div>
</Link>) : ( <div /> )}
```

This will take me to a /details/12345 (isbn10 number)

The thing I have a hard time to understand is how to for example
`setState({iPressedThisBook})` when pressing `<Link>` or if i can use the part after `/12345` to create like a filter

Because in `App` the `Route` will be hooked up as...

```
<Route path="/details/:id" render={() => (
          <BookDetailedView
            bookStateUpdated = {this.bookStateUpdated}
            book = {this.state.books}
          />
)}/>
```

I, later on, want to grab the `:id` so that I make for example a `this.props.book.find(:id)` inside of my `<BookDetailedView>`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In order to receive the path param in you component, you need to first connect your component with `withRouter` HOC from `react-router` so that you can access the Router props and get the path `params` from the `match` props as `this.props.match.params.id`

Sample Code:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class BookDetailedView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var id = this.props.match.params.id


    }
}
export default withRouter(BookDetailedView) ;
```

or simply passing it with render prop in route as

```
<Route path="/details/:id" render={({match}) => (
          <BookDetailedView
            bookStateUpdated = {this.bookStateUpdated}
            book = {this.state.books}
            id={match.params.id}
          />
)}/>
```

From the React Documentation of [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

> **match**
>
> A match object contains information about how a `<Route path>` matched
>   the URL. `match` objects contain the following properties:
>
> - params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding    to the dynamic segments of the path
> - isExact - (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing    characters)
> - path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building    nested s
> - url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building    nested s
>
> You’ll have access match objects in various places:
>
> 1. Route component as `this.props.match`
> 2. Route render as ({ match }) => ()
> 3. Route children as ({ match }) => ()
> 4. withRouter as this.props.match
> 5. matchPath as the return value
>
> If a Route does not have a path, and therefore always matches, you’ll
>   get the closest parent match. Same goes for withRouter

Comment: Glad I was able to explain it properly :)

Comment: `this.props.computedMatch.params.id`, I got it from computedMatch

Comment: Is there a way to access math.params at App level? `matchPath()` seems to be the only way I guess but some of my routes are dynamic hence don't match some path.

Comment: @SibasishMohanty Please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684017/react-router-v4-nested-match-params-not-accessible-at-root-level/52752990#52752990

Comment: Thanks. The approach makes sense. I am actually storing some route params in my redux store so that my <App /> can access those which is working just fine but I am not sure if this approach of storing routing info in the redux store is the right approach. Your thoughts? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @SibasishMohanty This may not be the best way to handle certain things but with Route params, there is no other way but to lift the state up into a common parent or even a store (flux or redux) to access the values throughout the app

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I will once consider revamping my route structure so that I can work with `matchPath()` else I will stick with the redux approach.

Answer (score -4):

You can access :id by doing
this.props.params.id

you can handle routing many ways, you don't have to do a 
you can also handle it in a function .

```html
function doSomethingWhenClicked(id)
{
      doSomething();
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/example/'+id
      });   
      
 }
```

and bind this function on a onclick element

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question in the least. Downvoted because irrelevant and incomplete answer.