# get parameter value from url using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, url, react-router-v4

I want to get the id value from this React Router:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/api">
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/pm" exact component={PaymentMethod}/>
        <Route path="/pw" exact component={PaymentWeb}/>
        <Route path="/rg" exact component={Registrasi}/>
        <Route path="/bonus/:id" exact component={BonusScreen}/>
        <Route path="/hb" exact component={HistoryBonus}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

in my `BonusScreen` I tried to print the value by using this :

```
const userId = this.props.match.id;
console.log(this.userId);
```

from the browser I try to access the URL like this:

```
bonus/NGO628567652201
```

But it always returned `undefined`.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [get-path-params-in-react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468837/get-path-params-in-react-router-v4/45469647#45469647)

Comment: You tagged this [tag:api] but that says "DO NOT USE: Tag with the library you mean, [api-design], or something else appropriate instead.". You should fix that.

Answer (score 21):

In case of anyone having this problem.
The correct would be:

```
const userId = this.props.match.params.id;
```

**05/2020 UPDATE USING REACT ROUTER V4 AND HOOKS**

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

//Then inside your component
const { id } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`const id = this.props.computedMatch.params.id`