# Accessing params of a wildcard path using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a deeply nested component that can be navigated to a lot of different ways, so I'm using a wildcard so I don't have to write out all the possible routes, something like:

```
   <Route path={'**/post/new'}>
     <CreatePost {...props} />
   </Route>
```

However, now I need to get and use information from where the user came from in the create post component, so if their paths were:

```
/en/10249/discussion/13353/thread/24/post/new
/en/10015/discussion/14233/post/new
/fr/10350/link/155/post/new
```

I would need the params:

```
/en/:b_Id/discussion/:d_Id/thread/:t_Id/post/new
/en/:b_Id/discussion/:d_Id/post/new
/fr/:b_Id/link/:l_Id/post/new
```

including `en`, `fr`, `discussion`, `thread` and `link`, but because I replaced the params with a wildcard I don't have access to those params anymore. These are just a small subset of path examples that can reach `/post/new`, and why I needed to replace all routes with a wildcard.

I'm currently thinking of parsing the URL by splitting it by `/` and reading relevant data that way, but I'm looking if there are better alternative approaches.

Is there a way I can write this where I don't need to type out every possible route, while still splitting up the path into separate params?

Answer (score 0):

`react-router` automatically includes path parameters in the component props.

In your `<CreatePost>` component, use:

```js
this.props.match.params.d_Id
```

and so on.

---

For more info, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468837/get-path-params-in-react-router-v4).